# Swift Format Date

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

This is probably really simple, I have tried lots of different methods but it doesnt seem to work.

I have the following date format in a text field:

> Saturday, 2 January 2016 12:00

held as:

```
  var str = "\(dobTextField.text!)"
```

I would like to convert the string above into the format:

> YYYY-mm-dd

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For Swift 2

Check this :

```
let str = "Saturday, 2 January 2016 12:00"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm" 
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let outputA = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(outputA!))
```

Output :

> 2016-01-02