# Date formatting using datepicker

Tags: swift, date

I am brand new to Swift so please be patient if I am asking the obvious.
I have a date picker and a label. On changing the date on datepicker the label displays the date/time in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss. My code is

```
@IBAction func DtPicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker)
{
    let strDate = String(describing: sender.date)
    lblShowShifts.text = strDate
}
```

which works fine

My problem is I just want to show the date as dd-mm-yyyy (and then calculate the number of days from a control date)
I am getting lost looking at dateformatter etc and seem to be going round in circles trying various permutations. Can anyone help - thanks in anticipation

Comment: There are countless examples of formatting dates in Swift. Please do some searching. If you have a specific issue then post what you have tried and explain the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Format Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316207/swift-format-date)

Answer (score 2):

@IBAction func DatePickerAction(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let strDate = String(sender.date)
    lblShowShifts.text = strDate

    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let currenttDate  = NSDate()
    let dateString = String(sender.date)

    //Default formatter for UIDatePicker -> "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
    //Fisrtly you need to give the formmater in which date is coming
      and then later change it according to your requirements
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

    let secondDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

    let date1 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(currenttDate)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(secondDate!)

    //Find number of days between two dates
    let flags = NSCalendarUnit.Day
    let components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: [])

    //Here you can do the calculations

    print("number of days between current date and today\(components.day)")


}
```

Comment: Thanks Ishika - the above pretty much answers my questions (with a bit of tweaking.) The only query that arises is I replaced the print("number of days  etc) with a label.text statement (lblShow.text = String("number of days etc) - it calculates the date difference right but outputs it in the format <<Number of days etc  Optional(x)>> where x is the datedifference. Can anyone explain this. I have tried looking for an explanation without success.

Comment: @Sgt_1381 Please unwrep the optional value by placing exclamation sign at the end.

Comment: Thanks Ishika - much appreciated

Comment: @Sgt_1381 : You welcome...And did the solution worked or you require something else ?

Comment: If I use the exclamation mark at the end of the line I am getting an error "Cannot force unwrap value of non-operional type '( )"

Comment: Which swift version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Swift 3